# How can i get more user debug logging related to kerberos for alfresco?

Tags: linux, kerberos, alfresco

I am running alfresco community edition 3.4c on a debian linux. I have problems getting the kerberos authentication in order. The biggest problem is that do not seem to have any sort of user logs.

what i am using already:
    log4j.logger.org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.KerberosAuthenticationFilter=debug
    log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.webdav.auth.KerberosAuthenticationFilter=debug
    log4j.logger.org.alfresco.smb.protocol=debug
    log4j.logger.org.alfresco.fileserver=debug

I've also checked if the users actually reach the server, and they do, (also on a linux firefox outside of domain, i seem to be able to log in).

Can anyone help me get more user logging?

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have to set the logging options in "webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties" and not in the alfresco-global.properties file. apparently that one overrides the global properties file.

Answer (score 0):

As you've spotted, you can't put log4j configuration into your alfresco-globals file. That's only used for Spring related configuration, and not log4j stuff.

If you want your own custom log4j file, without touching the system one, place it in alfresco/extension and call it {something}-log4j.properties (eg custom-log4j.properties) and it'll be used on the next start.

If you look at `alfresco/logging-context.xml` you'll see the list of places that Alfresco looks for logging config, and http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Developing_an_Alfresco_Module#log4j.properties is worth a read if you're new to log4j and how Alfresco uses it.